# my android emulator keeps stopping

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

This is my login app.
My app keeps craching.

Program code:

```
package ru.foodrobot.wma;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestHandle;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmResults;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm mRealm;
    private Realm mRealmInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){

        mRealm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        mRealm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
        mRealmInstance = mRealm.getInstance(config);

        //the code was here - 29.12.17
        //**********
        try {
            RealmResults User = mRealmInstance.where(Config.class).equalTo("name", "token").findAllAsync();
            if (User.size() > 0) {

                String nameOfUser = User.get(0).toString();

            } else if (User.size() == 0) {
                        /* Log.e("query","query size is "+User.size()); */
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.add("email", "r.amerzyanov@foodrobot.ru");
        rp.add("password", "123456");

        RequestHandle post = client.post("https://wms-amerzyanov.foodrobot.ru/api/v1/auth", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // Root JSON in response is an dictionary i.e { "data : [ ... ] }
                // Handle resulting parsed JSON response here
                try {
                    String tokenString = response.getString("token");

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    Config myConfig = mRealm.createObject(Config.class);
                    myConfig.name = "token";
                    myConfig.tokenValue = tokenString;
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my logcat looks like this:

12-29 13:54:30.042 19758-19758/ru.foodrobot.wma E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: ru.foodrobot.wma, PID: 19758
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.foodrobot.wma/ru.foodrobot.wma.MainActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
                                                                  - Class 'Config' has been added.
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                   Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
                                                                  - Class 'Config' has been added.
                                                                      at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
                                                                      at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.(OsSharedRealm.java:184)
                                                                      at io.realm.internal.OsSharedRealm.getInstance(OsSharedRealm.java:254)
                                                                      at io.realm.BaseRealm.(BaseRealm.java:124)
                                                                      at io.realm.BaseRealm.(BaseRealm.java:93)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.(Realm.java:153)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:424)
                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:342)
                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:282)
                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:353)
                                                                      at ru.foodrobot.wma.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628

Answer (score 1):

Your application is crashing because you changed the structure of your data.

In case you don't want to lose the data you have stored, it is necessary that you configure a migration to handle this type of situation. However, if you are still in development and your scheme changes frequently you can use:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder ()
     .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded ()
     .build ()
```

For more information on how to configure your migration:
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete your app and install it again. Also, you can replace your RealmConfiguration with this piece of code:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                           .Builder()
                           .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                           .build();
```

Comment: I use  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()  though it did not help. App is not debugged.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4844) can help you to find the problem.